# WCF Data Services: SaveChanges: An error occurred while processing this request

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-data-services

I get an 'An error occurred while processing this request' Exception when I try to Save some changes from my WPF-Application to a WCF-Data-Service. Loading all Records works fine, but saving them doesn't work.

Hope you can help.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DBEntities _dbEntities;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dbEntities = new DBEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:49256/DataService.svc/"));
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var user in _dbEntities.User)
        {
            treeView1.Items.Add(user.Name);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _dbEntities.MergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly;
            User user = new User(){Age = 1, ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test"};
            _dbEntities.AddToUser( user);
            _dbEntities.SaveChanges();
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message+ ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

There are no more exception details.

After setting UseVerboseErrors = true the following exception message appears:

Unable to update the EntitySet 'User' because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation.

Comment: You are going to need to post some exception details.  Or code that is failing.

Comment: Can you provide any additional information?  What's your entity model based on (EF, LINQ-to-SQL, custom)?  Is there any additional exception information provided?  Can you set your `UseVerboseErrors` to `true` to see what additional information is returned?

Comment: `UseVerboseErrors` is your friend.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this error if your underlying 'User' table doesn't have a [primary key identified](http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2009/09/09/fixing-the-system-data-updateexception-definingquery-and-no-lt-insertfunction-gt-error.aspx).  How is your entity set up (EF, LINQ-to-SQL, etc.) and what's your underlying repository (SQL, etc.)?  I'll update my answer accordingly.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
public class WcfDataService1 : DataService<PhaetonServiceEntities>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
         config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Cities", EntitySetRights.All);
        // config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use EntitySetRights.All. It hepls me

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.